# How to remove first two rows and 1st column of a csv file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, powershell

I am completely new to Windows programming. I need immediate help to develop a script that can chop off first two lines of a CSV file and first data column of the same csv file as its blank. Rest of the content can be written to another CSV file.

1st row : total volume 37, 37, 38

2nd row : total tickets 1000

```
 , instrument, side, quantity
 , OK , OK, OK
```

Any solution with a batch file or PowerShell is welcome for this task.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use PowerShell, this is fairly easy:

```
$content = Get-Content foo.csv
# Remove the first comma and whitespace from the file before further processing.
# I don't know how well the CSV parser likes an unnamed column
$content = $content -replace '^\s*,\s*'
# Parse CSV
$csv = ConvertFrom-Csv $content
# Write everything but the first two records back to the file
$csv | Select-Object -Skip 2 | Export-Csv foo.csv
```

Note, though, that your input format is particularly poor CSV. Spaces around field values are preserved in nearly every implementation and you're inconsistent on that front.

Eventually you probably want to filter the column or rows depending on whether there are values. In which case the above part will become relevant.

Comment: I'd skip the conversion steps, as they're unnecessary here. `(Get-Content foo.csv) -replace '^\s*,\s*' | select -Skip 2 | Out-File foo.csv` would suffice.

Comment: FYI the parser creates a name begining by h for the unnamed column (H1 , H2 etc..)

Answer (score 0):

It's surpisingly easy in batch:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=," %%i in ('more +2 file.csv') do echo %%i >>new.csv
```

(Note: empty lines will be removed)

This will not remove an existing first token, but you say, it is always empty

Answer (score 0):

same as @Joey without removing first column

```
(gc C:\temp\csv.csv)  |Convertfrom-Csv |select instrument,side,quantity -Skip 2
```